# How to check Django security vulnerabilities and how to fix them

Tags: django, python-3.x, security, django-rest-framework

*Before all I use Django 2.1 + Python 3.6*

I have to admit that Django is a framework that makes the life of a developer a lot easier even if it is relative.

Now that we've written a Django project, done the tests, deployed its web app;

**Questions:**

- What are the security points that are not particularly covered by
  Django?
- Can we have a vulnerabilities checklist related to sites written with
  Django?
- What are the important security tests for ensured the stability of an app written in Django?

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/security/. Otherwise this question is off-topic for this site (much too general)

Comment: As for security threats: OWASP has some checklists that one probably better takes a look at before deploying the system: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project#OWASP_Top_10_for_2013

Comment: https://gauravvjn.medium.com/secrets-of-security-in-a-django-application-0dfb41957eb0

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [Observatory by Mozilla](https://observatory.mozilla.org/) site to scan the security status of your site. The site also includes third-party scanners which test other security aspects of your site.

Here's an example of the scan results of a given site:

[image: Security status grade]

The best grade to get is A+ (scores can even exceed 100%), but don't be surprised a site scores a straight F (fail), even though the site has passed the basic deployment checklist.

To improve your site security, ensure you have these settings in your `settings.py`:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Strict'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 300  # set low, but when site is ready for deployment, set to at least 15768000 (6 months)
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
```

Then use the [SRI Hash Generator](https://www.srihash.org/) to ensure all your scripts are loaded securely from third-party sites.

Finally, the most challenging and time-consuming to implement is the Content Security Policy (CSP), particularly if the site is large, contains a lot of third-party code, and has a lot of inline scripts and styles scattered all over the project. To make the task easier, you can install [Mozilla's django-csp](https://github.com/mozilla/django-csp) and use your browser's console to track the security violations in your code. You will also need to fill in the following settings in your `settings.py`:

```
CSP_DEFAULT_SRC = ("'none'",)
CSP_STYLE_SRC = ("'self'",)
CSP_SCRIPT_SRC = ("'self'",)
CSP_FONT_SRC = ("'self'",)
CSP_IMG_SRC = ("'self'",)
```

[This site helps to explain about CSP and what to do with inline scripts.](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/)

Optionally, you can install [django-referrer-policy](https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-referrer-policy) to set the Referrer-Policy header for added security (and higher grade!).

I am a beginner myself, and all the above are based on my research and what I did to improve my site security.

Comment: `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` causes `Could not open the page, too many redirects` error on mobile browsers.

Answer (score 14):

one of the security check you can perform is  [Deployment checklist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/)

Run

```
manage.py check --deploy
```

other security check can be referred in [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/security/)